# Filter high pitched sounds in real time on Linux

Tags: linux, audio

I want to filter high pitched sounds in real time on Linux. So for example when watching a movie, if there is a big old TV or something and it has a high frequency sound that makes the ears ring, I would like to filter only those high frequencies if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is technically called a [low-pass filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter).

You can tell [MPV](https://mpv.io/) (arguably the most efficient and best quality media player for linux) to apply a low-pass filter like this:

```
mpv --af=lowpass=f=3200 Titanic.mp4
```

Alternatively you can configure Pulseaudio (an audio layer coomonly used on linux desktops) to apply a LADSPA low-pass filter to all audio.  This is described in detail [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/869822/how-to-add-a-low-pass-filter-to-a-system-wide-pulseaudio-profile) for Debian-based systems.

Comment: This is good enough, although I was thinking of something system wide.

Comment: I suggest you update the question to clarify that you prefer system-wide solutions.  Also helpful if you mention more detailed what you mean by "system-wide" - i.e. do your perception of "system" include _all_ access to audio then you will prefer a filter for ALSA, if only common desktop-oriented access to audio then Pulseaudio filtering is more suitable - or perhaps you will be interest in modern desktop audio via Pipewire...